# Declarative Jenkins pipeline: how to remove branches from the Project without deleting them from svn?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

We have Multi branch pipeline project to build on every commit.
Since each bug and feature are done in a separate branch - my list of branches in Jenkins project (multi branch pipeline)automatically grows very fast.

I would like to keep branches # under 15 to be displayed in Jenkins.
Problem is that we **DONT REMOVE** feature branches after merging to main branch(master) - therefore Jenkins still indexing them.

My investigation led to:

1) I can delete Jenkinsfile from each of these branches manually which is poor solution.

2) I tried to use "Orphaned Item Strategy" in declarative pipeline, but it only will delete "builds" on certain branch rather than the branch itself from Jenkins view.

I am new to Jenkins and Declarative pipeline - maybe there is a good way to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question for **How to remove the branches without deleting from SVN**, AFAIK it is not possible and not ideal way of doing.All that you need to do it to cleanup the branches in SVN. Because **`the reason for using multibranch-pipeline is to have pipeline for every individual branch`**.

As you said, **the problem is not cleaning up the branches in the SVN and deleting the Jenkinsfile in each of these branches is really a bad solution**. Having auto build for all the branches and PRs will create load on Jenkins and further will slow down the build and deployment process.

So as a workaround what we can do is to **reduce the load on Jenkins by restricting the branches to build automatically when a commit happens**, something like this.

[image]

**`This will auto build only for master, develop branches and all the PRs`** which are mandatory. Apart from these any other feature branches or User Story branches need to be build manually with "Build Now" for which the job gets created automatically as part of multibranch-pipeline.

You can even exclude/include the branches by configuring accordingly. But this needs to monitored regularly to exclude and include them whenever required.

[image]

Hope this helps to some extent. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your post and suggestion for decrease Jenkins workload. In my case this measure is unnecessary as usually no one modifies the old branches, so they are not built by multibranch pipeline. Although they are indexed by scm step everytime. But I guess unless we chose to remove branches in SVN, this is the only way to keep multibranch working for us.